# How to click on iframe button

Tags: iframe, paypal

I'm working on iframes and I tried this method to click on iframe but I got error

I want to click on PayPal button

[image]

iframe body

[image]

I tried this

```
cy.getIframeBody('iframe').find('#paypal-animation-container').click()


//command.js
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframeBody', (iframe) => {
    return cy.get(iframe).then($iframe => {
      const $body = $iframe.contents().find('body')
      cy.wrap($body)
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot click on nor otherwise directly interact with the DOM of an iframe hosted on a different domain.

And even if you *could* via some JS hook that iframe made available (which it does not), PayPal buttons open a window for payment. A click that opens a window needs to come from a direct user action (actual user clicking on the button), not a script action, otherwise most modern browsers will block such a scripted window from opening.

In summary what you want to do cannot be done, and even if it *could* be done it would not work.

Comment: Is there any alternative way to tackle this?

Comment: if cypress don't support cross domain testing then, Can we implement this in selenium?